# jquery is not reacting

Tags: jquery, html

I am creating a few paragraphs that should react with a button in jQuery.

When I press the button nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm embedding jQuery by using this link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googkeapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#test").hide(); 
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p id="test">This is another paragraph</p>
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors.

Comment: Clearly it seems you have not included jquery lib

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself, not as an image

Comment: **Never** include pictures of your code. Include your code in the question. It's basic good manners if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Its a typo - googleapis ,you are using as googkeapis.